# EJB container initialized callback in WildFly

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

We deploy our project as war or ear project according to project specification.
On war deployment we can receive context initialized from ServletContextlistener. This listener indicates all startup singleton beans @PostConstruct methods are called by container. That was what we need.

On ear deployment, we realized that ServletContextlistener is on another classloader and called regardless of all startup singleton beans @PostConstruct methods are called.
So, how we can be notified by container after all startup singleton beans @PostConstruct methods are called.

EAR deployments not isolated class loading behavior.
Server : Wildfly-10.0.Final
JDK: 1.8.u92

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "@PostConstruct" methods are the actual callbacks.

Comment: I need an event just right after all @PostConstruct are called.

Comment: I don't quite understand the nature of your problem, generally speaking CDI events could be a solution.